# How to store an input with various data types into a single variable (String, Int, Date, List)

Tags: java, object, oop

In the UI, I need to support to select the condition and based on the condition must provide the input. Inputs can be one of the listed below:

- QUANTITY
- DATE
- AMOUNT
- LIST - ["Option1", "Option2"] - Multiple Selection
- RANGE - (Min and Max)

Once selected it will get populated as a JSON.

The Java class looks like the below with the fields and its getters and setters:

```java
private String condition;
private String value;
private List<String> valueList;
private String valueType;
private int minValue;
private int maxValue;
```

For AMOUNT, as the below:

```json
{
  "condition": "Basket Value",
  "value": "5",
  "dataType": "AMOUNT",
}
```

For RANGE, as the below:

```json
{
  "condition": "Percentile",
  "dataType": "RANGE",
  "minValue": 10,
  "maxValue": 60
}
```

For LIST, as the below:

```json
{
  "condition": "Options",
  "dataType": "LIST",
  "valueList": ["option1", "option2"]
}
```

Instead of having `value`, `valueList`, `attributeMin`, and `attributeMax`. How can I store it in a single variable?

Is using `Object` the best solution? Is there any other solution? I cannot use `var` in Java for this.

```java
Object inputValue;
```

The data will be saved to MongoDB.

Comment: Why would you want to store four obviously separate pieces of data in a single variable?

Comment: You should use different classes for each type, and use the `dataType` as the "discriminator".

Comment: Also, shouldn't the type of the last example be "LIST", not "RANGE"?

Comment: @VGR Such requirement is pretty common

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with polymorphic serialization and deserialization. This example uses records and sealed types, but should also work when rewritten to not use sealed and using "normal" POJOs.

I use Jackson (`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2`) for this, with the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation to declare the mapping from the `dataType` property to the appropriate classes. I have only listed the examples in your question, but doing this for QUANTITY and DATE should follow from this.

Define an interface as the root of the types:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "dataType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AmountValue.class, name = "AMOUNT"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RangeValue.class, name = "RANGE"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ListValue.class, name = "LIST"),
})
public sealed interface Condition 
        permits AmountValue, 
                ListValue, 
                RangeValue {

    String condition();

}
```

And the individual records of each type:

```java
public record AmountValue(
        String condition, 
        String value) implements Condition {
}
```

```java
public record RangeValue(
        String condition, 
        int minValue, 
        int maxValue) implements Condition {
}
```

```java
public record ListValue(
        String condition, 
        List<String> valueList) implements Condition {

    public ListValue {
        valueList = List.copyOf(valueList);
    }

}
```

An example for serializing and deserializing:

```java
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var conditionHolder = new ConditionHolder(
                new AmountValue("Basket Value", "5"),
                new RangeValue("Percentile", 10, 60),
                new ListValue("Percentile", List.of("option1", "option2")));

        var mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        System.out.println("serialized format");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(conditionHolder));
        System.out.println("===============================");
        System.out.println("deserialized result");

        ConditionHolder deserialized = mapper.readValue("""
                {
                  "conditionList" : [ {
                    "dataType" : "AMOUNT",
                    "condition" : "Basket Value",
                    "value" : "5"
                  }, {
                    "dataType" : "RANGE",
                    "condition" : "Percentile",
                    "minValue" : 10,
                    "maxValue" : 60
                  }, {
                    "dataType" : "LIST",
                    "condition" : "Percentile",
                    "valueList" : [ "option1", "option2" ]
                  } ]
                }
                """, ConditionHolder.class);
        System.out.println(deserialized);
    }

    public record ConditionHolder(List<Condition> conditionList) {

        public ConditionHolder {
            conditionList = List.copyOf(conditionList);
        }

        public ConditionHolder(Condition... conditions) {
            this(List.of(conditions));
        }

    }

}
```

Output (with added linebreaks in deserialized result for readability):

```
serialized format
{
  "conditionList" : [ {
    "dataType" : "AMOUNT",
    "condition" : "Basket Value",
    "value" : "5"
  }, {
    "dataType" : "RANGE",
    "condition" : "Percentile",
    "minValue" : 10,
    "maxValue" : 60
  }, {
    "dataType" : "LIST",
    "condition" : "Percentile",
    "valueList" : [ "option1", "option2" ]
  } ]
}
===============================
deserialized result
ConditionHolder[conditionList=[
  AmountValue[condition=Basket Value, value=5], 
  RangeValue[condition=Percentile, minValue=10, maxValue=60],
  ListValue[condition=Percentile, valueList=[option1, option2]]
]]
```

Obviously, to actually use these types and their value in code, you will have to do `instanceof` checks, but once pattern matching switch lands (probably in Java 21), that type of handling can be further simplified. Alternatively, it might be possible to define necessary evaluation or behaviour through methods in `Condition`, but if that is possible depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

If you need to "manually" perform the serialization or deserialization (e.g. because the library you use doesn't provide support for polymorphic serialization/deserialization), then you need to mimic what Jackson does. That is, for serialization, determine the actual type, add the *discriminator* property (`dataType`) with the right value to the JSON object, and then the properties of the actual object. For deserialization, use the *discriminator* property (`dataType`) to decide which type to create, and read the properties of that type from the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

At glance, I can see that you can use a HashMap variable.

```
HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Now you can enter any type of data without any issue.
Make sure that you use proper validation against null values.
Hope this help.